# How to retrieve unsaved password

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, password, history

How can I Retrieve unsaved passwords from history on safari or hard drive of a macbook pro

password not saved on keychain.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, user input is not cached in Safari. But hopefully the web site you want to log in to allows you to reset/resend your password